# .htaccess redirect one domain to another incliuding specific query string

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, query-string

basally I need to redirect

`http://www.old-domain.com/news.php?NewsID=30888`

to

`http://www.new-domain.com/news.php?NewsID=30888`

using htaccess however only if the query string is as above.  Any other query str`ings I need to continue to go to`http://www.old-domain.com/news.php?NewsID=whatever_querystring.

So I need to match the 30888 and then redirect to a whole new site including the `news.php?NewsID=30888`.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your .htaccess and try;

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^NewsID=30888 [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.old-domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.new-domain.com%{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to test your Query string and the host name:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} NewsID=30888 [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^(www\.)?old-domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)          http://www.new-domain.com/$1 [L,R]
```